# Using SugarCRM 6.5 and Java: Get all contacts for account

Tags: java, soap, sugarcrm

I am writing a SOAP Service to get all Contacts for an Account in Java.
I just found the get_relationships(..) method.

But it is not working as I expected. I definitely have contacts related to that account, I tested this querying the DB directly.

I found this [documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Method_Calls/get_relationships/)

And I don't really understand what this field means: related_module_link_name_to_fields_array

What am I doing wrong?

```
accountID="cad15b8a-d70b-13eb-f295-55ca158ec988"
String query = "";
String[] relatedFields= new String[]{"first_name", "last_name", "email1"};
Link_name_to_fields_array[] linkedFields = new Link_name_to_fields_array[]{null};
String orderby = "";
resultVersion2 = binding.get_relationships(sessionID, "Accounts", accountID, "contacts", query, relatedFields, linkedFields , 0, orderby);
```

And this is my translation of the referred example from php to java:

```
Link_name_to_fields_array[] linked = new Link_name_to_fields_array[]{new Link_name_to_fields_array("contacts", new String[]{"id", "first_name", "last_name"})}; 
binding.get_relationships(sessionID, "Accounts", "400808a8-7f3a-39d9-abfd-557aed2f9a89",
        "opportunities", " opportunities.name IS NOT NULL ", new String[]{"id", "name"}, linked, 0, orderby);
```